# Makefile with pattern and directories

Tags: design-patterns, makefile, directory, target

For a game I've a lot of textures to refenerate, this can take some times and so I only want to regenerate modified one instead of all of them.

I've a makefile with a structure similar to this one (which here s simplified for the example):

```
all:\
  wall

wall:\
  wall/red\
  wall/blue\
  wall/mixed

wall/%:\
  wall/%/top.png\
  wall/%/left.png\
  wall/%/right.png\
  wall/%/down.png\
    echo $@ $<

wall/red/%.png:\
  .source/wall/model/%.png
    convert $< -fill "rgb(255,0,0)" -colorize 15,15,15,0 -level "0%,100%,0.8" $@

wall/blue/%.png:\
  .source/wall/model/%.png
    convert $< -fill "rgb(0,0,255)" -colorize 15,15,15,0 -level "0%,100%,0.8" $@

wall/black/%.png:\
  .source/wall/model/%.png
    convert $< -fill "rgb(0,0,0)" -level "0%,100%,0.4" $@

wall/white/%.png:\
  .source/wall/model/%.png
    convert $< -fill "rgb(255,127,0)" -level "0%,70%,1.2" $@

wall/mixed/%.png:\
  wall/white/%.png\
  wall/black/%.png\
  .source/wall/mask/%.png
    convert $(word 1,$^) $(word 2,$^) $(word 3,$^) -composite $@
```

My problem here is that :

```
wall/%:
    echo $@
```

is working (it return me "wall/red", "wall/blue" and "wall/mixed") but :

```
wall/%:\
  wall/%/top.png\
  wall/%/left.png\
  wall/%/right.png\
  wall/%/down.png\
    echo $@
```

don't works (it return that there is no rules to build "wall/red" for "wall") and I don't know why because I've already seen rules like :

```
obj/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
```

that works correctly.

Comment: Run `make -Rd` and you should be able to pinpoint where the implicit rule search gives up, either due to an incorrect rule or because the source files aren't there.

Comment: Source files were here, rules seemed correct, but I found make don't works right with rule with paterns and without commands, so in all of them, I've put '@true' as a command and it seems to works

Comment: Can you share where exactly you put `@true`?

Comment: On this example I can't because I've simplified the rules a lot, particularly, I've excluded the tmp directory where all works are done, but for example, I've put echo $@ in the wall/% rule and if I remove the action, it don't works, so I've put @true in place of echo $@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `wall/%: wall/%/top.png ...` recipe is not matched, because some of the required files (`top.png`, `left.png`, `right.png`, `bottom.png`) in `.source/wall/model/` are missing.

This behavior is described in the [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro)

> In order for the pattern rule to apply, its target pattern must match the file name under consideration and all of its prerequisites (after pattern substitution) must name files that exist or can be made

### Proof

This is my test makefile:

```
# test.mk
wall/%: wall/%/top.png wall/%/bottom.png
        @echo running: $@

wall/red/%.png: .source/wall/model/%.png
        @echo running: $@
```

It is reproducing the issue:

```
$ make -f test.mk wall/red
make: *** No rule to make target `wall/red'.  Stop.
```

Let's try to create `top.png`:

```
$ mkdir -p .source/wall/model/top.png
$ make -f test.mk wall/red
make: *** No rule to make target `wall/red'.  Stop.
```

Still does not work. Add also `bottom.png`:

```
$ mkdir -p .source/wall/model/bottom.png
$ make -f test.mk wall/red
running: wall/red/top.png
running: wall/red/bottom.png
running: wall/red
```

Works now!

Comment: I think that my problem was a bit of unreachable source files and rules without commands that made my makefile not running, now that I've put a command in all case with a pattern, I no longer have a problem. I thought that make would warn us that there is eligible rules but source files are missing to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You have one backslash too many in the `wall/%` rule. If you change this:

```
wall/%:\
  wall/%/top.png\
  wall/%/left.png\
  wall/%/right.png\
  wall/%/down.png\
    echo $@
```

to this:

```
wall/%:\
  wall/%/top.png\
  wall/%/left.png\
  wall/%/right.png\
  wall/%/down.png
    echo $@
```

it works perfectly. With that extra backslash, you are telling Make that `echo` is a prerequisite of the rule. And since there is no file called "echo", and the makefile gives no way to build it, Make cannot use the `wall/%` rule for anything.

You could have discovered this bug quite easily if you had prepared a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).